# CloudFront signed URLs throwing 403 Forbidden errors

Tags: http, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I’m trying to use CloudFront as a CDN for my video on demand website.

I’ve created a HTTP distribution (because I need to stream to iOS devices, so RTMP is unsuitable), and set the origin to be my S3 bucket where my video files are stored. I’ve also created a CloudFront key pair.

Using the AWS PHP SDK, I create a signed URL like this (in Laravel):

```
$cloudfront = AWS::get('CloudFront');

$streamHostUrl = 'http://REDACTED.cloudfront.net';
$resourceKey = 'videos/output/hls/REDACTED.m3u8';
$expires = '+10 minutes';

$signed_url = $cloudfront->getSignedUrl(array(
    'url' => sprintf('%s/%s', $streamHostUrl, $resourceKey),
    'expires' => $expires,
    'private_key' => base_path('cloudfront.pem'),
    'key_pair_id' => 'APKAIPX4UJ26KJ65PKIA',
));
```

And that creates a URL looking how I’d expect.

The path of the private key file is correct, and the specified object (**REDACTED.m3u8**) in my bucket has the permission of **Everyone** being able to **View/Download** (as does all the other objects in that folder). I then embed the URL in a web page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>HTTP Live Streaming Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video src="<?php echo $signed_url; ?>" height="300" width="400" controls>
    </video>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, this throws a **403 Forbidden** error to the console.

What am I doing wrong? Why can’t a retrieve any objects via CloudFront?

I’ve disabled the requirement for signed URLs and when I access the object without query string parameters (i.e. http://REDACTED.cloudfront.net/videos/output/hls/REDACTED.m3u8) the video displays, so there’s a problem when I enable the need for signed URLs.

Comment: Hi Martin, am facing the same issue. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @Sridhar Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your expires is correctly converted to UNIX timestamp. According to this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.CloudFront.CloudFrontClient.html#_getSignedUrl you need to pass timestamp there